# Display swf into a native window

Tags: flash, cross-platform

I need to deploy a flash application on Windows and Mac(and mabe Linux) and currently i have it loaded into an custom air window but that makes it run even slower.
I've tried using Qt but if i load my app into QAxWidget that would work on Win but not on Mac, if i load it width QWebKit it does not connect to my Amf server. I researched a bit Haxe and NME but that works terribly(swf stops runnning during resize, the window does not repaint itself during resize).

Is there anything that enables me to load the swf in a native window and enable my swf to call through ExternalInterface different functions(to save some data)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check more deeply into NPAPI. I have done something like this in a previous project (I have done it with gtk+ and NPAPI). I'm trying to implement it only in xlib right now.

check this post: [Hosting Flash won't load swf ressources (xml, image, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538218/hosting-flash-wont-load-swf-ressources-xml-image-etc)