# Hosting Flash won't load swf ressources (xml, image, etc.)

Tags: c, gtk, adobe, flash, npapi

I tried to achieve at first a swf reader with gtk2 on my unix machine. Worked, I could render simple swf files. Now, I'm trying to add a configuration to my flash file with xml configuration, add image, etc. Failed, won't get pass geturlnotify().
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h> 
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include "npupp.h"

#define FLASH_PLUGIN_SO "./libflashplayer.so"

void *flash_plugin_handle;

NPNetscapeFuncs browserFuncs;
NPPluginFuncs   pluginFuncs;

GtkWidget *main_window;

char* fileName = NULL;
NPStream *       stream;
const char * uagent = "Axt/1.0";

//Default window size
int WINDOW_XSIZE = 800;
int WINDOW_YSIZE = 600;

//Default child window position (flash player)
int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition = 0;

NPError (*iNP_Initialize)(NPNetscapeFuncs* bFuncs, NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs);
NPError (*iNP_Shutdown)();
char*   (*iNP_GetMIMEDescription)();

void* loadFlashPluginSo() {
  void *handle;

  handle = dlopen(FLASH_PLUGIN_SO, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
  if(!handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[-] error loading libflashplayer.so: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(1);
  } 
  fprintf(stderr,"[+] loaded libflashplayer.so\n");
  return handle;
}

void* loadSymbol(void *handle, const char *name) {
  char *error;
  void *ret;

  ret = dlsym(handle, name);

  if((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[-] error loading symbol %s: %s\n", name, error);
    exit(1);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr,"[+] loaded symbol %s, address: %p\n", name, ret);
  }
  return ret;
}

void loadNPEntryPoints(void *handle) {
  iNP_Initialize=loadSymbol(handle, "NP_Initialize");
  iNP_Shutdown=loadSymbol(handle, "NP_Shutdown");
  iNP_GetMIMEDescription = loadSymbol(handle,"NP_GetMIMEDescription");
}

void printPluginEntrypoints(NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs) {
  fprintf(stderr,"[*] NPP struct:\n");
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_size:                 %8d\n",pFuncs->size);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_version:              %8d\n",pFuncs->version);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_NewProcPtr:           %p\n", pFuncs->newp);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_DestroyProcPtr:       %p\n", pFuncs->destroy);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_SetWindowProcPtr:     %p\n", pFuncs->setwindow);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_NewStreamProcPtr:     %p\n", pFuncs->newstream);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_DestroyStreamProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->destroystream);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_StreamAsFileProcPtr:  %p\n", pFuncs->asfile);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_WriteReadyProcPtr:    %p\n", pFuncs->writeready);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_WriteProcPtr:         %p\n", pFuncs->write);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_PrintProcPtr:         %p\n", pFuncs->print);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_HandleEventProcPtr:   %p\n", pFuncs->event);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_URLNotifyProcPtr:     %p\n", pFuncs->urlnotify);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- javaClass:                %p\n", pFuncs->javaClass);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_GetValueProcPtr:      %p\n", pFuncs->getvalue);
  fprintf(stderr,"\t- NPP_SetValueProcPtr:      %p\n", pFuncs->setvalue);
}

NPError NPN_GetValueProc(NPP instance, NPNVariable variable, void *ret_value) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:%p, variable:%d, abi_mask:%d\n", instance, variable, 0);

    switch (variable) {
    case NPNVSupportsXEmbedBool:
      *((int*)ret_value)= PR_TRUE;
      break;
    //Unix and solaris fix
    case NPNVToolkit:
      *((int*)ret_value)= NPNVGtk2;
      break;
    case NPNVnetscapeWindow:
      *((int*)ret_value)= PR_TRUE;
      break;
    default:
      *((int*)ret_value)=PR_FALSE;
      break;
    }
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

const char* NPN_UserAgentProc(NPP instance) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_UserAgentProc instance:%p\n", instance);
    return uagent;
}

NPError NPN_GetURLProc(NPP instance, const char* url, const char* window) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_GetURLProcPtr:%p, url: %s, window: %s\n", instance, url, window);
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPIdentifier NPN_GetStringIdentifierProc(const NPUTF8* name) {
    return (NPIdentifier)0x41424344; //Unique
}

static 
gboolean plug_removed_cb (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[!] plug_removed_cb\n");
    return TRUE;
}

static void
socket_unrealize_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] socket_unrealize_cb\n");
}


static NPWindow *
npwindow_construct (GtkWidget *widget) {
  NPWindow *npwindow;
  NPSetWindowCallbackStruct *ws_info = NULL;

  GdkWindow *parent_win = widget->window;

  GtkWidget *socketWidget = gtk_socket_new();

  gtk_widget_set_parent_window(socketWidget, parent_win);
  gtk_widget_set_uposition(socketWidget, xPosition, yPosition);

  g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "plug_removed", G_CALLBACK(plug_removed_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "unrealize", G_CALLBACK(socket_unrealize_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroyed), &socketWidget);


  gpointer user_data = NULL;
  gdk_window_get_user_data(parent_win, &user_data);

  GtkContainer *container = GTK_CONTAINER(user_data);
  gtk_container_add(container, socketWidget);
  gtk_widget_realize(socketWidget);

  GtkAllocation new_allocation;
  new_allocation.x = 0;
  new_allocation.y = 0;
  new_allocation.width = WINDOW_XSIZE;
  new_allocation.height = WINDOW_YSIZE;
  gtk_widget_size_allocate(socketWidget, &new_allocation);

  gtk_widget_show(socketWidget);
  gdk_flush();

  GdkNativeWindow ww = gtk_socket_get_id(GTK_SOCKET(socketWidget));
  GdkWindow *w = gdk_window_lookup(ww); 

  npwindow = malloc (sizeof (NPWindow));
  npwindow->window = (void*)(unsigned long)ww;
  npwindow->x = 0;
  npwindow->y = 0;
  npwindow->width  = WINDOW_XSIZE;
  npwindow->height = WINDOW_YSIZE;

  ws_info = malloc(sizeof (NPSetWindowCallbackStruct));
  ws_info->type = NP_SETWINDOW;
  ws_info->display = GDK_WINDOW_XDISPLAY(w);
  ws_info->colormap = GDK_COLORMAP_XCOLORMAP(gdk_drawable_get_colormap(w));
  GdkVisual* gdkVisual = gdk_drawable_get_visual(w);
  ws_info->visual = GDK_VISUAL_XVISUAL(gdkVisual);
  ws_info->depth = gdkVisual->depth;

  npwindow->ws_info = ws_info;
  npwindow->type = NPWindowTypeWindow;

  return npwindow;
}

static NPStream *
npstream_construct() {
    NPStream *stream = malloc(sizeof(NPStream));
    stream->url=fileName;
    stream->notifyData = 0x00000000;

    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_StreamConstructed: %p\n", stream);

    return stream;
}

bool NPN_GetPropertyProc(NPP npp, NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier propertyName, NPVariant *result) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_GetPropertyProc: %p\n", result);
    result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
    result->value.objectValue= (NPObject*)1;
    return TRUE;
}


bool NPN_InvokeProc(NPP npp, NPObject* obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_InvokeProc: %p\n", result);
    result->type= NPVariantType_String;
    result->value.stringValue.utf8characters=fileName;
    result->value.stringValue.utf8length=strlen(fileName);
    return TRUE;
}

void NPN_ReleaseVariantValueProc(NPVariant *variant) {
}

void NPN_ReleaseObjectProc(NPObject *obj) {
}

NPObject*  NPN_CreateObjectProc(NPP npp, NPClass *aClass) {
    return (NPObject*)1;
}

NPObject*  NPN_RetainObjectProc(NPObject *obj) {
    return (NPObject*)1;
}

NPError NPN_GetURLNotifyProc(NPP instance, const char* url, const char* window, void* notifyData) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_GetURLNotifyProc:%p, url: %s, window: %s\n", instance, url, window);
    return 0;
}

NPN_GetURL, NPN_GetURLNotify, and NPP_URLNotify

void initNPNetscapeFuncs(NPNetscapeFuncs *bFuncs) {
  int i=0;

  for(i=1; i<sizeof(*bFuncs)/sizeof(ssize_t); i++)
    *(((ssize_t*)bFuncs)+i)=i+1000;

  bFuncs->geturl=NPN_GetURLProc;
  bFuncs->getvalue=NPN_GetValueProc;
  bFuncs->uagent=NPN_UserAgentProc;
  bFuncs->getproperty=NPN_GetPropertyProc;
  bFuncs->getstringidentifier=NPN_GetStringIdentifierProc;
  bFuncs->invoke=NPN_InvokeProc;
  bFuncs->releasevariantvalue=NPN_ReleaseVariantValueProc;
  bFuncs->releaseobject=NPN_ReleaseObjectProc;
  bFuncs->createobject=NPN_CreateObjectProc;
  bFuncs->retainobject=NPN_RetainObjectProc;
  bFuncs->geturlnotify=NPN_GetURLNotifyProc;
  bFuncs->size= sizeof(bFuncs);
  bFuncs->version= (NP_VERSION_MAJOR << 8) | NP_VERSION_MINOR;;
}

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

static void checkError(const char* str, NPError err) {
  if(err == NPERR_NO_ERROR)
    fprintf(stderr, "[+] %s: success\n", str);
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "[-] %s: failed (%d)\n", str, err);
    fflush(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int c;
  extern char *optarg;

  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:w:h:x:y:")) != EOF){
    switch (c) {
      case 'f':
        fileName = optarg;
        fprintf (stderr, "[+] Filename: %s\n", optarg);
        break;
      case 'w':
        WINDOW_XSIZE = atoi(optarg);
        fprintf (stderr, "[+] WINDOW_XSIZE: %s\n", optarg);
        break;
      case 'h':
        WINDOW_YSIZE = atoi(optarg);
        fprintf (stderr, "[+] WINDOW_YSIZE: %s\n", optarg);
        break;
      case 'x':
        xPosition = atoi(optarg);
        fprintf (stderr, "[+] Position in x: %s\n", optarg);
        break;
      case 'y':
        yPosition = atoi(optarg);
        fprintf (stderr, "[+] Position in y: %s\n", optarg);
        break;
      case '?':
        if (optopt == 'f' | optopt == 'w' | optopt == 'h')
          fprintf (stderr, "[-] Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if (isprint (optopt))
          fprintf (stderr, "[-] Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf (stderr,"[-] Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
          exit(-1);
      default:
        fprintf(stderr,"[-] Usage: %s -f <swffile> -x <xsize> -y <ysize>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
  }

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_set_usize (main_window, WINDOW_XSIZE, WINDOW_YSIZE);
  gtk_widget_set_uposition (main_window, xPosition, yPosition);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (main_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
  gtk_widget_realize(main_window);
  gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);
  fprintf(stderr,"[+] created GTK widget\n");

  flash_plugin_handle = loadFlashPluginSo();

  loadNPEntryPoints(flash_plugin_handle);
  fprintf(stderr,"[+] initialized flash plugin entry points\n");

  initNPNetscapeFuncs(&browserFuncs);
  fprintf(stderr,"[+] initialized browser functions\n");

  checkError("NP_Initialize", iNP_Initialize(&browserFuncs, &pluginFuncs));

  printPluginEntrypoints(&pluginFuncs);

  NPWindow *npwin = npwindow_construct(main_window);
  fprintf(stderr,"[+] created NPWindow widget\n");

  NPP_t *instancep = malloc(sizeof(NPP_t));
  memset(instancep,0,sizeof(sizeof(NPP_t)));
  NPP instance     = instancep;

  NPSavedData* saved = malloc(sizeof(NPSavedData));
  memset(saved,0,sizeof(sizeof(NPSavedData)));

  stream = npstream_construct();
  uint16_t stype;

  char *xargv[]= {"quality", "bgcolor", "width", "height", "allowScriptAccess", "loop" };
  char *xargm[]= {"high", "#000000", "1360", "768", "always", "false" };


  checkError("NPN_New", pluginFuncs.newp("application/x-shockwave-flash", instance, NP_EMBED, 0, xargv, xargm, saved));
  checkError("NPN_SetWindow", pluginFuncs.setwindow(instance, npwin));
  checkError("NPN_NewStream", pluginFuncs.newstream(instance, "application/x-shockwave-flash", stream, 0,  &stype));


  FILE *pp;

  char buffer[8192];
  pp = fopen(fileName,"rb");

  int len;

  while((len=fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pp)) != 0) {
    pluginFuncs.writeready(instance, stream);
    pluginFuncs.write(instance, stream, 0, len, buffer);
  }

  fclose(pp);

  checkError("NPN_DestroyStream",pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance, stream, NPRES_DONE));

  free(stream);

  gtk_main ();

  checkError("NPN_Destroy",pluginFuncs.destroy(instance, &saved));


  checkError("NP_Shutdown", iNP_Shutdown());

  dlclose(flash_plugin_handle);
  return 0;
}
```

If I load a swf with no xml. It works.
When I had a config to my xml. It stops.

Here's the ouput I get:

```
~/test-flash$ ./test-flash -f xml_sample.swf -w 400 -h 600 -x 15 -y 15
[+] Filename: xml_sample.swf
[+] WINDOW_XSIZE: 400
[+] WINDOW_YSIZE: 600
[+] Position in x: 15
[+] Position in y: 15
[+] created GTK widget
[+] loaded libflashplayer.so
[+] loaded symbol NP_Initialize, address: 0x7ff03fb634d0
[+] loaded symbol NP_Shutdown, address: 0x7ff03fb634c0
[+] loaded symbol NP_GetMIMEDescription, address: 0x7ff03fb63870
[+] initialized flash plugin entry points
[+] initialized browser functions
[+] NP_Initialize: success
[*] NPP struct:
        - NPP_size:                        0
        - NPP_version:                     0
        - NPP_NewProcPtr:           0x7ff03fb63990
        - NPP_DestroyProcPtr:       0x7ff03fb63980
        - NPP_SetWindowProcPtr:     0x7ff03fb63970
        - NPP_NewStreamProcPtr:     0x7ff03fb63960
        - NPP_DestroyStreamProcPtr: 0x7ff03fb63910
        - NPP_StreamAsFileProcPtr:  0x7ff03fb63920
        - NPP_WriteReadyProcPtr:    0x7ff03fb63950
        - NPP_WriteProcPtr:         0x7ff03fb63940
        - NPP_PrintProcPtr:         0x7ff03fb63900
        - NPP_HandleEventProcPtr:   0x7ff03fb638f0
        - NPP_URLNotifyProcPtr:     0x7ff03fb63930
        - javaClass:                (nil)
        - NPP_GetValueProcPtr:      0x7ff03fb63860
        - NPP_SetValueProcPtr:      (nil)
[+] created NPWindow widget
[D] NPN_StreamConstructed: 0x25ce5e0
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:14, abi_mask:0
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:268435469, abi_mask:0
[D] NPN_UserAgentProc instance:(nil)
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:15, abi_mask:0
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:15, abi_mask:0
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:18, abi_mask:0
[+] NPN_New: success
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:14, abi_mask:0
[+] NPN_SetWindow: success
[D] NPN_GetURLNotifyProc:0x25cc720, url: javascript:top.location+"__flashplugin_unique__", window: (null)
[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:0x25cc720, variable:15, abi_mask:0
[+] NPN_NewStream: success
Lenght: 455
[D] NPN_UserAgentProc instance:0x25cc720
[+] NPN_DestroyStream: success
[D] NPN_GetURLNotifyProc:0x25cc720, url: sample.xml, window: (null)
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

I tried something like this (code is in NPN_GetURLNotifyProc function) . but then, my app freeze inside my geturlnotifyproc...

```
NPStream s;
uint16 stype;
memset(&s,0,sizeof(NPStream));
s.url = strdup(url);
fprintf(stderr, "URL: %s\n", s.url);
checkError("NPN_NewStream", pluginFuncs.newstream(instance,"text/html",&s,0,&stype));    
    writeStream(instance, &pluginFuncs, &s);
pluginFuncs.urlnotify(instance,url,NPRES_DONE,notifyData);
checkError("NPN_DestroyStream", pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance,&s,NPRES_DONE));
            free((void*)s.url);
```

Comment: Can't believe how this NPAPI documentation is so incomplete and non-trivial.

Comment: I made a dll to read libfashplayer.so, too see exacly what is going on.... I'll keep you guys posted.

Comment: For now, I presume you have to create a new stream for each ressources (xml, image, etc.) to your plugin instance.

Comment: How do I handle the stream.. do I have to use libcurl or something for data transefering...?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think it's libcurl. What about g_timeout within the geturlnotify that call a process for getting the stream dynamically?

Comment: very very cool that you would write your own NPAPI host for this, nice work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add the notify to my stream...

```
NPError NPN_GetURLNotifyProc(NPP instance, const char* url, const char* target, void* notifyData) {
    fprintf(stderr,"[D] NPN_GetURLNotifyProc:%p, url: %s, window: %s, data: %p\n", instance, url, target, notifyData);
    NPStream s;
    uint16 stype;

    memset(&s,0,sizeof(NPStream));
    s.url = strdup(url);
    s.notifyData = notifyData;

    fprintf(stderr, "NPP: %p URL: %s\n", instance, url);

    checkError("NPN_NewStream", pluginFuncs.newstream(instance,"text/html",&s,0,&stype));    
    writeStream(instance, &pluginFuncs, &s);

    checkError("NPN_DestroyStream", pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance,&s,NPRES_DONE));
    free((void*)s.url);
    pluginFuncs.urlnotify(instance, url, NPRES_DONE, notifyData);
    return 0;
}
```

**I have now a standalone gtk application who can run compiled flash (swf).**
Hope it helps someone in the future. I recommend doing a plugin to read another plugin (aka Sniffer) to actually know which function is called ("and how things works") to have a decent log file to work with.